# Calculating font size for a CCLabelTTF

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, cocos2d-iphone, font-size

Does anyone know a method to calculate the maximum font size for a CCLabelTTf of a specific CGSize?  I have seen ways of calculating a font size for a specific width but not width and height.  This calculates the font size for width:

```
-(int) getSizeForString:(NSString*)aString InWidth:(int)width
{
    int startSize = 24;

    while (startSize > 5) {
        CGSize aSize = [aString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:startSize]];
        if (aSize.width <= width) return startSize;
        startSize--;
    }

    return 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to calculate size of text with a specific font, you can in the same way check height...
 If you want to set string in more than one line you should use

```
[NSString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
```

This return you a CGSize for string with more than one lines if the text don't fit to maxSize

Comment: `label` would be a `NSString`.